# Subsequent ajax responses are very slow

Tags: ajax, django

In the all apps ajax are generally very fast, in one particular app(newly developed) for the first time also ajax response is fast but on the subsequent calls ajax response is very slow thereafter in the rest of the app's ajax responses also very slow.

Is there any way to debug the issue? I am saving few values in session also in the new app. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should check this helpful article [link](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1851233)

Comment: most of them are django-autocomplete light  based drop down field, first time its fine but only on subsequent calls im facing issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, the issue was, i was saving the form in session because of that my subsequent calls slowed down.

Answer (score 0):

In php session_write_close() can solve this issue. In django maybe you can use something like that.